# Bind Gridview Datasource with Linq (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview, datasource

Basically, what I want to do is to bind a Linq query to the datasource of a gridview. Here is my code so far :

```
ddgDossiers.DataSource = (From c In dbConnection.Campaigns.AsQueryable Select c).ToList
ddgDossiers.DataBind()
```

It compiles and doesn't complain of anything.

```
<asp:GridView ID="ddgDossiers" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" AllowSorting="True"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableViewState="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="35"
PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" PagerStyle-Position="TopAndBottom"
BorderWidth="1" GridLines="Both" BorderColor="#000000" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr">
<PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" HeaderText="UniqueID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left"
        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="1%" HeaderStyle-Width="1%"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridTitle" ItemStyle-CssClass="rowReport" SortExpression="UniqueId">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUniqueID" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItem("Campaign.CampaignId").ToString%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The error is pointing on this line :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblUniqueID" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItem("CampaignId").ToString%>' />
```

And saying : No default member found for type 'Campaign'.

Is there anything to do with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do the .ToList to bind it.  Does Campaigns table contain a CampaignId column?

Comment: Try Removing Campaign. and just use CampaignId 
<%#Container.DataItem("CampaignId")

Comment: My bad. It was a test. I did already with CampaignId only. And yes the table contains this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change line

```
Text='<%#Container.DataItem("Campaign.CampaignId").ToString%>'
```

To

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CampaignId") %>'
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!!!! Works like a charm. I would rate up your answer, but I do not have enough rep yet ^^.